# Any method to not skip space in a rule?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I want to implement an ".ascii" directive for my assembler. Everything between " ... " is considered an ascii string, which is written to my target file.

```
 mips32code : instruction+ # StartPlace
            ;

instruction : OPCODE_RTYPE rd COMMA rs COMMA rt                     # RTypeInstruction
            | OPCODE_ASCII '"' ascii '"'                            # ASCIITypeInstruction
            ;

ascii       : instruction # asciiformat
            | NAME        # asciiname
            ;

INT   : [0-9A-Fa-f]+
      ;

NAME  : [A-Za-z]+[0-9]+
      ;

LABELD        : '!' 
              ;

LABELDEF      : ':' 
              ;

COMMA         : ',' 
              ;

VALUE         : ('$'|'0x')+
              ;

LINE_COMMENT
              : (';'|'//') ~[\r\n]* -> skip
              ;

BLOCK_COMMENT
              : ('/*' .*? (EOF | '*/')) -> skip
              ;

WS
              : (' ' | '\r' | '\n') -> channel(HIDDEN)
              ;
```

Here, "NAME" is for the ascii string. I got everything working, my visitor successfully writes the ascii string to my test file, however ANTLR4 does not match space in my ascii string. How would I do that now? I don't want to match space and keep it ignored for all other rules. But is it possible to implement exceptions, which would match space in this one case?

EDIT:
I'm also kinda confused why ANTLR4 always matches space in the beginning and the end of a string:

[image: Problem 1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you well, I think you want to let quoted Strings with spaces an all elements there. You can take a work around and tell the lexer "anything but for..." and it will respect spaces until your next quote. I recommend you define your Strings (between quotes) like this:

```
DOUBLEQUOTED_STRING
    :   '"' ( ~('"') )* '"' ;
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I tried this, but it still isn't working and gives me a no viable alternative at input "Hello"-error. (I wrote "Hello World"). As I said, I just want space to be matched between my quotes "Hello World     ALALA" as I write this space into a test file later (through my visitor).

Comment: Ah, I see. It works perfectly now. I slowly understand regex more and more, even if it's very painful to me. So, thank you very much for help!

Answer (score 0):

Space is not matched because you are sending it to the HIDDEN channel. You didn't post entire grammar here - I mean since you are talking about visitors, there should be some parser rules here as well.
So either do something on the HIDDEN channel, or don't send the space there.
Define space like

```
WS: ' ';
```

and than use WS in OPCODE_ASCII or whereever. For matching more spaces, use quatifiers.

Comment: So, I added the parser rules. I made some tiny mistake here by the way. Also, I can't match WS as it would mess up my whole grammar (I have even more parser rules for the other assembler formats, but didn't post them here as they're not important and required for this problem). I just want WS to be matched in rule "ascii".